# Static final String field is null at runtime only with a specific value

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm creating a Java EE Web project using Java 7 and GlassFish 4.1.1. My IDE is NetBeans.

When refactoring some code from a repository class I replaced the string "USERS" with a static final field on my model class. Immediately after doing this (clean and build) I had an IllegalArgumentException from my service and found that the field was being read as null.

Model class:

```
public class User {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "USERS";
    public static final String PRIMARY_KEY = "ID";

    private String id;    
    private String name;

    public User(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

User Repository, before:

```
public List<User> get() throws RepositoryException
{
    try {
        return service.retrieve("USERS");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new RepositoryException("Retrieval failed.", ex);
    }
}
```

User Repository, after:

```
public List<User> get() throws RepositoryException
{
    try {
        return service.retrieve(User.TABLE_NAME);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new RepositoryException("Retrieval failed.", ex);
    }
}
```

**Probably the strangest thing about this** (but maybe quite revealing?) is that if I change the value of the field the problem disappears.

```
// This works!
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "USERSS";
```

Of course, the value of TABLE_NAME is now wrong.

Here's what I've tried:

- Looking for compile errors (there are none)
- Clean and build
- Undeploying from GlassFish, then redeploying
- Restarting NetBeans
- Making the field not final
- Google

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: That is indeed very strange, I don't think you can reproduce that behavior with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I guess rename your table to `USERSS` :)

Comment: Hm, have you tried to set a breakpoint at the problematic line and stepped through with a debugger? Maybe this will shed some light on it.

Comment: could you please share some code of your service class and, if you use jpa the used database?

Comment: looks like some bug in Java/glassfish. Have you tried to reproduce it on some other java/glassfish version?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this bug on any other machine and haven't tried any different Java/glassfish versions.
The bug is not present in the final version, so my best guess is some fluke within GlassFish itself?